# Android Rounded Bottom Menu Transparent Background With Shadow

Tags: android

Recently I wanted to build something like this

[image: i wanted for]

But unfortunately, I can't make it shadow in the rounded corner and also it seems there were extra background here (even I have set android:background to transparent)

any idea?

**Main layout**

```
.....
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <include layout="@layout/main_menu_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"/>
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
....
```

**included layout**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_shadow_gradient" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_rounded_corner"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/one_x"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_homehdpi"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/one_x"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/home_menu_home"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/one_x"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/one_x"
            android:id="@+id/home_selected"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom_menu_selected"/>
    </LinearLayout>
.........
```

bg rounded corner

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

It turns out into

[image: wrong]

Ps.
I have tried without using include and it doesn't work either.

Comment: You should remove the background in the parent LinearLayout but in any caseythe shadow can't work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CardView` instead.

Create a shape:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="18dp" android:topRightRadius="18dp" /> 
</shape>
```

and set it to your `CardView`, like this:

```
cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_shape);
```

Or (haven't tested this)

```
android:background="@drawable/your_shape";
```